# How to configure notification channels to show multiple notifications

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I've written the code for two notification channels. But one notification triggers the other one so both of the notifications are shown. I've already tried `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` for `pendingIntent` but it's the same.

`NotificationHelper` class:

```
public class NotificationHelper extends ContextWrapper {
    public static final String channel1ID = "channel1ID";
    public static final String channel1Name = "Add transactions reminder";
    public static final String channel2ID = "channel2ID";
    public static final String channel2Name = "Due and overdue bills";
    private NotificationManager mManager;

    public NotificationHelper(Context base) {
        super(base);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            createChannels();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void createChannels() {
        NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(channel1ID, channel1Name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel1.enableLights(true);
        channel1.enableVibration(true);
        channel1.setLightColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
        channel1.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        getManager().createNotificationChannel(channel1);

        NotificationChannel channel2 = new NotificationChannel(channel2ID, channel2Name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel2.enableLights(true);
        channel2.enableVibration(true);
        channel2.setLightColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
        channel2.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        getManager().createNotificationChannel(channel2);
    }

    public NotificationManager getManager() {
        if (mManager == null) {
            mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
        return mManager;
    }

    public NotificationCompat.Builder getChannel1Notification(String title, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        int reqCode = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), reqCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channel1ID)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    }

    public NotificationCompat.Builder getChannel2Notification(String title, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        int reqCode = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), reqCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channel2ID)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

`AlertReceiver` class:

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String TAG = "AlertReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);

        //add transactions reminder
        NotificationCompat.Builder nb1 = notificationHelper.getChannel1Notification(
                notificationHelper.getString(R.string.trans_notify_title), notificationHelper.getString(R.string.notification_msg)
        );
        notificationHelper.getManager().notify(1, nb1.build());

        //due and overdue bills
        NotificationCompat.Builder nb2 = notificationHelper.getChannel2Notification(
                notificationHelper.getString(R.string.bills_notify_title), notificationHelper.getString(R.string.notification_msg)
        );
        notificationHelper.getManager().notify(2, nb2.build());
}
}
```

first notification:

```
public void startAlarm(Calendar c) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        int reqCode = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, reqCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.notification_set_at) + timeString + getString(R.string.everydayy), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

second notification:

```
private void setNotifications(int dueDayOfYear) {
        LocalDate dueDate = LocalDate.ofYearDay(LocalDate.now().getYear(), dueDayOfYear);
        LocalDateTime prevDay = dueDate.minusDays(1).atStartOfDay().plusHours(14).plusMinutes(7);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlertReceiver.class);
        int reqCode = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, reqCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, prevDay.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

(`plusHours` and `plusMinutes` are used to test and to make sure that the notifications are set at different times)

I think something's wrong with the `AlertReceiver` class but I can't figure it out. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.
It's when calling `notify()` in the `AlertReceiver` class. I solved it by generating a unique id when calling it.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
        int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis(); //this is the fix

        //add transactions reminder
        NotificationCompat.Builder nb1 = notificationHelper.getChannel1Notification(
                notificationHelper.getString(R.string.trans_notify_title), notificationHelper.getString(R.string.notification_msg)
        );
        notificationHelper.getManager().notify(id, nb1.build());

        //due and overdue bills
        NotificationCompat.Builder nb2 = notificationHelper.getChannel2Notification(
                notificationHelper.getString(R.string.bills_notify_title), notificationHelper.getString(R.string.notification_msg)
        );
        notificationHelper.getManager().notify(id, nb2.build());
```